# ReactJS component lifecycle methods with fat arrow functional component

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Requriement:

1. Need to listen for firebase database ref.
2. Want to remove the listener if a component is unmounted,

In similar component below:

```
const Main = ({
  collapsed,
  db,
}) => 

{
 const intl = useIntl();

useEffect(() => {
  try {
    db.ref("AdminDashBoardDepartment").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    alert("error occurred. " + error);
  }
}, []);

/* Following does not work on fat arrow functional component but works on a class based component.
componentWillUnmount()
{
  console.log("Component is about to unmount.");
}*/

/* class based component has render method but arrow based function does not. */
return (
  <main>

    <h3> you will render element.</h3>

  </main>
);
};


export default Main;
```

I have seen a few of SO solutions, none mentions the titled problem, most of which are this vs that, so far what I found.

I can convert this component to a class based one, no problem but is that only solution?

I'm already using
`useEffect()` and need a listener.

So, What is the possibility to get lifecycle aware methods in react component or what is the way I can use a firebase db ref when needed and unmount it automatically or if the component is unmounted?

Comment: From the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off) you should use `off()` to remove it

Comment: You can return a function inside useEffect. This function will act similar to `componentWillUnmount`, so add the off inside it

Comment: @Akshay I know that. Its not about how to remove db ref listener.

Comment: @Akshay Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the listener, return a function that calls `off()` from the `useEffect` handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let listener;
  try {
    listener = db.ref("AdminDashBoardDepartment").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    alert("error occurred. " + error);
  }
  return () => db.ref("AdminDashBoardDepartment").off("value", listener);
}, []);
```

Also see the React documentation on [Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).